# rails split not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, time

I'm using rails `split` to `split` the time up.

I have this:

```
MM = time.split(':')[1]
HH = time.split(':')[0]
```

Time has this:

```
19:30:00
```

I'm just wanting

```
19:30
```

If i do `HH + ':' + MM` i should get the format back i want correct?

If i do the splits manually in byebug i get eventhign back fine.

But if i do HH in byebug i get

```
*** NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `HH' for main:Object

nil
```

However MM works fine?

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Time#`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime):

```
 Time.parse('19:30:00').strftime('%H:%M')
 #=> "19:30"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is already a string, I would use a regular expression:

```
time.match(/(.*):/)[1]
```

In a quick benchmark I did, this was nearly 20 times faster then using Time.parse